# getting 404 in random product detailed page

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I am running a magento website but sometimes i get 404 when i try to open a product detail page.
when i click any product from product listing page and get redirected to product page , sometimes it gives 404 for any random product(not any particular product). I checked system.log and exception.log but it doesn't show any error regarding that.

is there any particular cause for this issue ? and is there any solution of that?

I refer below link but when i set cookie 30 it just logout customer and admin but product page doesn't through any 404 error.

[Magento 1.9.3.1 404 Product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152869/magento-1-9-3-1-404-product-page)

Comment: Check its "enabled", "Catalog, Search","Assign product in website"

Comment: what this?? @Indian

Comment: check comment again please

Comment: @Indian ofcouse its enabled and it comes under catalog, search thats why there are visible in frontend

Comment: You mean you are not try to access it directly using URL but try to access it from listing page right?

Comment: Yes those products are listed in product listing page but when i click on any product it gives 404 and it happens randomly not every time for every product but just some random time@Indian

Comment: Have you did indexing? Also check its URL when its give 404 error and compare URL with its URL key.